# ASP.NET Chart control multiple series databinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, charts

Using the following table as an example:

```
   TimeStamp          ValueA ValueB Name
   5/1/2011 12:00:00  100    150    Item1 
   5/1/2011 12:00:00  101    151    Item2 
   5/1/2011 12:10:00  110    160    Item1 
   5/1/2011 12:10:00  111    151    Item2 
   5/1/2011 12:20:00  102    170    Item1 
   5/1/2011 12:00:00  112    171    Item2
```

I have a treeview with Item1 and Item2 as nodes with ValueA and ValueB selectable for each:

```
Item1
    -ValueA
    -ValueB
Item2
    -ValueA
    -ValueB
```

When the user selects ValueA or ValueB it should be added as a series and displayed on the chart.

The data is displayed properly but only for the last ItemX checked.  If you check Item1->ValueA and then Item2->ValueA on the treeview then update the chart using the code below the series will only display the ValueA for Item2

```
SqlDataSource sqlDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
            sqlDataSource.ID = "SQLDataSourceChart";

            foreach (TreeNode node in TagTreeView.CheckedNodes)
            {
                // Add a series to the chart
                Series series = Chart1.Series.Add("Series" + node.Value);
                series.ChartArea= "ChartArea1";
                series.ChartType = (SeriesChartType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType), charts[1], true);

                sqlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HistoricalDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                if (node.Depth > 1)
                {
                    sqlDataSource.SelectCommand = @"SELECT "+ node.Value + " [ExampleTable] WHERE [Name] = '" + node.Parent.Text + "' ORDER BY TimeStamp";

                    this.Page.Controls.Add(sqlDataSource);
                    Chart1.DataSourceID = "SQLDataSourceChart";

                    Chart1.Series["Series" + node.Value].XValueMember = "TimeStamp";
                    Chart1.Series["Series" + node.Value].YValueMembers = node.Value;

                }
            }
            Chart1.DataBind();
```

I think I am not clear on how the series are being added to the chart.  My original assumption was that the series are added to the chart with the name based on the node.Value when the foreach loop is processed giving a list of series that are then added to the chart on the databind.

What appears to be happening is that all of the series are being based on the legend with only the data for the last selected item on the treeview being visible in the chart.

What I want to happen in the end is the user can select any combination of ValueA and ValueB for either Item1 or Item2 and have the appropriate number of series show up on the chart.  Is this possible and if so what part of my approach is incorrect?

Based on further examination I think the reason I am getting the errors when ValueA is chosen for Item1 and ValueB for Item2 and the reason that the results are only returned for the last selected item is that the sqlDataSource.SelectCommand has the last value that was set in the foreach loop which would be for the last selected item.

Is there a way to tie a sqlDataSource to the specific series or so provide a separate query to each series to that when the data is bound to the chart each series sees the correct query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

I was not using the correct databinding method to achieve the results I was looking for.

To populate the data in each series the way I wanted requires using the Series.AddXY() method and a datareader object.

```
Series series = Chart1.Series.Add(node.Parent.Text + "-" + node.Value);
                series.ChartArea= "ChartArea1";
                series.ChartType = (SeriesChartType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType), charts[1], true);


                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringDefinedElsewhere);

                if (node.Depth > 1)
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand nodeQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT (Date + CONVERT(datetime,Time)) As TimeStamp," + node.Value + ", [ItemID] FROM EquipmentData WHERE [ItemID] = '" + node.Parent.Text + "' ORDER BY TimeStamp", sqlConnection);

                    SqlDataReader reader = nodeQuery.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        int value = (int)reader[node.Value];
                        DateTime TimeStamp = (DateTime)reader["TimeStamp"];

                        series.Points.AddXY(TimeStamp, value);
                    }
                    sqlConnection.Close()
                }
            }
            Chart1.DataBind();
```

Using this method you can select any combination of ValueA and Value B for Item1 and Item2 and get the data on the chart correctly.